# Login page keep refreshing whenever I try to login in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-9

I have done everything from the tutorial or otherwise but it still doesn't work.

**every time I enter my email and password in this code, the browser always seems to refresh and return to the login page again.**

I'm using laravel version 9.x.
anyone please help me to solve this.

**here's my LoginController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(){
        return view ("loginpage.login");
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ]);
 
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
 
            return redirect()->route('admindashboard');
        }
 
        return back()->withErrors([
            'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
        ])->onlyInput('email');
    }
```

**here's my web.php:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use App\Http\Controllers\SessionController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/admin',[AdminController::class, 'dashboardadmin'])->name("admindashboard");
Route::get('/analitik-iklan',[AdminController::class, 'analiklan'])->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/analitik-keuangan',[AdminController::class, 'analuang'])->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/laporan-berita',[AdminController::class, 'lapber'])->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/add',[AdminController::class, 'add'])->name("tambahauthor");

Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'otentikasi'])->name('logingan');
```

**here's my form blade view:**

```
 <form action="{{ route('logingan') }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <input type="email" name="email" class="email" @error('email') is-invalid @enderror placeholder="Masukkan email" required autofocus>
            @error('email')
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {{$message}}
            </div>
            @enderror
            <input type="password" name="password" class="password" placeholder="Masukkan password" required>
            <a href="lupapassword">Lupa Password?</a>
            <input type="submit" value="Masuk" class="login">
        </form>
```

I expect it to authenticate, like after successful login, it will not go back to the login page again whenever I click a view that requires 'authentication'.